# Having trouble downloading a file through FTP. (wget, curl, aria2c)

Tags: curl, download, ftp, wget, aria2

I am having trouble downloading a file through FTP (ftp://ftp.pride.ebi.ac.uk/pride/data/archive/2017/11/PXD007635), this FTP site doesn't require any credential and I can download it directly by clicking it in my web browser. But when I tried to download it directly to my cluster, it doesn't work.

I tried wget:

```
wget ftp://ftp.pride.ebi.ac.uk/pride/data/archive/2017/11/PXD007635/OvCa100_classII_Rep#1.raw
```

And get this error:

```
--2020-08-01 18:35:22--  ftp://ftp.pride.ebi.ac.uk/pride/data/archive/2017/11/PXD007635/OvCa100_classII_Rep
Resolving bmiproxyp.chmcres.cchmc.org (bmiproxyp.chmcres.cchmc.org)... 10.199.92.254
Connecting to bmiproxyp.chmcres.cchmc.org (bmiproxyp.chmcres.cchmc.org)|10.199.92.254|:80... connected.
Proxy request sent, awaiting response... 404 Not Found
2020-08-01 18:35:23 ERROR 404: Not Found.
```

Then I tried curl

```
curl -O ftp://ftp.pride.ebi.ac.uk/pride/data/archive/2017/11/PXD007635/OvCa100_classII_Rep#1.raw
```

And get this error:

```
550 Failed to open file.
```

Finally I tried aria2c

```
aria2c ftp://ftp.pride.ebi.ac.uk/pride/data/archive/2017/11/PXD007635/OvCa100_classII_Rep#1.raw
```

And get this error:

```
08/01 18:38:03 [ERROR] CUID#7 - Download aborted. URI=ftp://ftp.pride.ebi.ac.uk/pride/data/archive/2017/11/PXD007635/OvCa100_classII_Rep#1.raw
Exception: [AbstractCommand.cc:351] errorCode=3 URI=ftp://ftp.pride.ebi.ac.uk/pride/data/archive/2017/11/PXD007635/OvCa100_classII_Rep
  -> [HttpSkipResponseCommand.cc:219] errorCode=3 Resource not found

08/01 18:38:03 [NOTICE] Download GID#9476c1bde9a8def1 not complete:
```

I am quite sure my cluster proxy setting is correct and based on aria2c error info, it seems like the resource site is down, but it works by just clicking and downloading in web browser. Would anyone give me any hint about that? Much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to simply replace "#" with "%23".